# Windows does not appear in the GRUB list

Tags: installation, dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

I have Ubuntu 13.04 and I want to add Win7. My problem is that the win7 disk is not recognized or not loaded after I restart, so I cant even start the installation. The grub gives me the usual suggestions about loading Ubuntu or running memory tests.
I've seen some text that says that I should install win7 before Ubuntu.

My Qs:

1. Do I have to uninstall Ubuntu first?
2. Can I ask the Grub to load the win7 installer?
3. In case I need to remove the ubuntu first, does deleting all the
   partitions from the HD is enough or should I use OS-installer from
   liveCD etc?

   for your time
   Tamir

Comment: You mean that you insert the DVD and the Windows installation doesn't start or that you can find in the grub your Windows system already installed?

Answer (score 0):

Please allow me to confirm - did you set up cd-rom drive as your first boot device in BIOS? This should launch directly to Windows installer.\

Please keep in mind that installing Windows after ubuntu will overwrite grub with default windows launcher, that would need corrected then. Also it's a good idea not to use the partition with Ubuntu to install Windows on it, as Ubuntu will got purged that way...

Assuming you proceed with the Windows installation then, you would need to reinstall grub to regain access to Ubuntu system and grub itself.

Some space might be needed at the beginning of the disk for grub to work though, so Windows can't be set up on the very beginning, I'd recommend leaving at least 16 MB of free data for boot record during Windows setting up.

Comment: Yes, i did set up the BIOS to boot from the CD. The CD is supposed to be OK, I tried it on a different PC, a week ago. Can the grub installation somehow interfere with the win7 detection? It doesn't make any sense :(

Comment: I guess I would remove the hard drive from boot hierarchy from BIOS and check the CD then. Perhaps for some reason there is another setting overwriting your boot sequence. This is sometimes set up as F12 to go to boot options. Grub shall not interfere with CD detection, for GRUB loads from the disk. And It is decided earlier whether to load a ystem from a disk or from a CD.

Comment: I tried that just now, it didn't work. Well maybe the CD is corrupted after all.

Thank you.